# I am trying to use install_github in devtools package but failing

Tags: r, github, installation, package, devtools

I am using Sierra MacOS 10.12.6 and running rstudio 1.2.5033 and R 4.0.3 on a macbook pro from early 2015.  Can anyone please let me know how to fix this issue?

First I got the following error :

Using github PAT from envvar GITHUB_PAT
Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
HTTP error 401.
Bad credentials

I then unset this PAT via
Sys.unsetenv("GITHUB_PAT")

However, now I get another error as in the example below and this occurs when installing any github package, almost identically, even the "line 34" below.  The dyld symbol binding and symbol not found error always occur and I also always get the same Warning in file(con, "r"). This dyld error seems to be related to the fact my OS is less than 10.13

I suppose that might answer the question but do I need to update the OS, actually?

Downloading GitHub repo jeremyrcoyle/gentmle2@HEAD
✓  checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/vf/l0sx2pbj71jdsknd5dq5p2c00000gp/T/Rtmp1Z3KtE/remotes3db121f76e4/jeremyrcoyle-gentmle2-20d253b/DESCRIPTION’ ...
─  preparing ‘gentmle2’:
✓  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
Warning in file(con, "r") :
cannot open file '/var/db/timezone/zoneinfo/+VERSION': No such file or directory
─  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─  checking for empty or unneeded directories
─  building ‘gentmle2_0.1.0.9000.tar.gz’

dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _utimensat
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _utimensat
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/INSTALL: line 34:  2818 Done                    echo 'tools:::.install_packages()'
2819 Abort trap: 6           | R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES= LC_COLLATE=C "${R_HOME}/bin/R" $myArgs --no-echo --args ${args}
Error: Failed to install 'gentmle2' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/vf/l0sx2pbj71jdsknd5dq5p2c00000gp/T//Rtmp1Z3KtE/file3db4fb67c07/gentmle2_0.1.0.9000.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Comment: as a test, perhaps git clone to local, R CMD build then R CMD INSTALL.

Comment: Yes, I can install locally no problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the R download page, R version 4.xx requires macOS 10.13 or higher. Your two options are to update your OS or to download and install an older version of R e.g. R-3.6.3.nn.pkg (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/)

Comment: Thanks.  So the answer appears to be “yes” I need to update the OS as I’d  prefer not to go backward in R versions.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't the answer you were looking for, but I can't see a way around it. Good luck